# Create-React-App installing in wrong drive

Tags: reactjs, npm

Im trying to make a new react app in a folder I have clearly saved on my D drive, with more than enough space, but every time I run `create-react-app` I get this error

```
Creating a new React app in D:\Projects\PostgreSQL Tutorial\client\client.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ENOSPC
npm ERR! syscall write
npm ERR! errno -4055
npm ERR! nospc ENOSPC: no space left on device, write
npm ERR! nospc There appears to be insufficient space on your system to finish.
npm ERR! nospc Clear up some disk space and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\tbpat\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-23T20_01_48_481Z-debug-0.log
```

Below is my drive sizes, and I have confirmed that the root folder for "D:\Projects\PostgreSQL Tutorial" is in the D: drive.

[image]

Comment: Your O/S drive has literally 0 bytes left?

Comment: Is there a reason my C drive would be filling up instead of the D drive where my react app is supposed to be installed

Comment: Regardless of the App, you really need to have free space on your C drive just for swap files to be possible.  It could be it makes a temp file and transfers it to the D: but being it can't create the temp file due to no space, it fails?

Answer (score 0):

Some things that I would try to do are:

Trying to run cache clean cmd:
`npm cache clean --force`. Could be helpful with resolving any potential issues with the package installation process.

Second thing to try is also trying to create folder inside of `D:\` disc instead of running command directly, as well as running the cmd as administrator.

Least thing to try is yarn instead of npm.